# jquery Date Format , date changes to today date

Tags: jquery

I have `datepicker` control to which when date is assigned there is some abnormal
issues related to format.

1. When date returned in `dd/mm/yyyy` format from server side
   and jquery dateformat is set to `dd/MM/yyyy` then date does not change
2. When date returned in `dd/mm/yyyy` format from server side
   and jquery dateformat is set to `dd-M-yy` then date changes to today date
   not as send by server side code

   ```
       if (startDate != null && endDate != null)
       {
           setDateFormat(startDate);
           setDateFormat(endDate);

           if (startDate.val() == "") {
               startDate.datetimepicker('setDate', new Date());
           }
           else {
               startDate.datetimepicker('setDate',    startDate.datetimepicker('getDate'));
           }

           if (endDate.val() == "") {
               endDate.datetimepicker('setDate', new Date());
           }
           else {
               endDate.datetimepicker('setDate', endDate.datetimepicker('getDate'));
           }
       }

       function setDateFormat(id) {
       id.datepicker({
           changeMonth: true,
           changeYear: true,
           dateFormat: "dd-M-yy"
       });
   }
   ```

Comment: show your code. What you tried?

Comment: You may find that this component for translating between date formats is helpful: http://blog.greatrexpectations.com/2013/04/04/translating-date-formats-in-javascript/